# Programmatically alter an excel rows or columns heigh

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Probably easy one. How can i change rows or column heigh?

```
 xlApp = new Excel.Application();
 xlApp.Visible = true;
 xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
 Excel.Workbooks xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
 xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(directoryPath + "\\" + fileName, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

 xlWorkSheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets; //Get all the sheets in the workbook
 xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkSheets.get_Item("Sheet1"); //Get the allready exists sheet
 Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
 Excel.Range chartRange;

 int colCount = range.Columns.Count;
 int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;

  xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowCount + 5, 1] = "Name and surname";
  chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("a" + (rowCount + 5), "e" + (rowCount + 5));
  chartRange.Font.Bold = true;

 xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
  xlWorkBook.Close(misValue, misValue, misValue);
  xlWorkSheet = null;
  xlWorkBook = null;
  xlApp.Quit();

  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  GC.Collect();
```

Try it with `xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Height = value;` but it doesn't work. `autoFit()` is working but i would like to work with my value.

Comment: Did you try using `OfficeOpenXml`? It is easier and you can do that in it. If you want, i could paste a bit of code to see what does it look like :)

Comment: Please do. So simple functions and so difficult to find.

Comment: `xlsgen` is probably similar than yours `OfficeOpenXml` http://xlsgen.arstdesign.com/core/rowsandcolumns.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you may be looking for RowHeight...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.rowheight(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: works for me. If I add `chartRange.RowHeight = 38;` to your code above (immediately below `chartRange.Font.Bold = true;`) then the row height is changed